# Neater way of writing a null check (Possibly without IFs?)

Tags: java, optimization, conditional-statements

I have a simple piece of code:

```
txtRequiredDate.setText(wwDateFormatter.format(todoEntity.getRequiredDate()));
txtRequiredDateDay.setText(dayOfWeek(todoEntity.getRequiredDate()));
txtDoneDate.setText(wwDateFormatter.format(todoEntity.getDoneDate()));
txtDoneDateDay.setText(dayOfWeek(todoEntity.getDoneDate()));
```

Problem is that sometimes the date is null (as it is optional to fill out). In those cases, the wwDateFormatter triggers a NullPointerException.

One way of fixing it, as I see it is:

```
if (todoEntity.getRequiredDate() != null) 
{
    txtRequiredDate.setText(wwDateFormatter.format(todoEntity.getRequiredDate()));
    txtRequiredDateDay.setText(dayOfWeek(todoEntity.getRequiredDate()));
}

if (todoEntity.getDoneDate() != null)
{
    txtDoneDate.setText(wwDateFormatter.format(todoEntity.getDoneDate()));
    txtDoneDateDay.setText(dayOfWeek(todoEntity.getDoneDate()));
}
```

But I was wondering if there is a more concise way of writing the above statement?

Thank You!

**Edit** I guess it's not that this isn't optimized, but rather the fact that I'd like to learn various ways of checking for nulls, especially if situation ever arises that I must have 30 of those statements, heh.

Comment: What's not optimized with that?

Comment: Seems pretty concise for Java code to me!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/how-to-avoid-null-statements-in-java

Comment: @nullpointer you can appear without ifs :)

Comment: Yeah, but you'll have to use either asserts (which the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html) suggest not doing) or use empty strings, which I don't see as a solution necessarily.  I think this code is fine as is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not wrap the formatter with a null-aware variant that returns an empty string if passed a null ?

You may also be interested in the [Null Object Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern). Also note [this blog](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/the-option-pattern), which discusses Scala's `Option` pattern and the equivalent in Java. These are both very useful patterns that you can make use of to mitigate your issue above.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your date strings are never null (use an empty string: `""` instead) - no more ifs needed.

Or you could use a non-null utility method (similar to what Brian suggested):

```
private String nonNull(String s) {
    return (s == null ? "" : s);
}

public void yourMethod() {
    txtRequiredDate.setText(wwDateFormatter.format(nonNull(todoEntity.getRequiredDate())));
    txtRequiredDateDay.setText(dayOfWeek(nonNull(todoEntity.getRequiredDate())));
    ...
}
```

Comment: But then down the road he might have to be checking for empty strings.  What if null is really the correct value to have by default?

Comment: empty strings won't create NPEs... I am just saying that it is easier to not allow null as a default value when possible.

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical reason why accessors/properties are good to avoid if possible. Try to get rid of exposing the entity's "raw" data and put the logic inside the entity itself - then you have your null check in one place.

```
txtRequiredDate.setText(todoEntity.formattedRequiredDate())
```

...where you do your null check in the entity method instead (and returning empty string or whatever if null).

Whether getters and setters really are evil or not, [old classic article in this subject](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-2003/jw-0905-toolbox.html), is up for debate, but at least having encapsulation in mind when designing entities is a good thing IMO.

Comment: I actually like this idea in my case! Although I am not 100% sure of how correct that would be, it seems logical to me!